# Install a trusted root certificate in PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, ssl-certificate, phantomjs, root-certificate

Is it possible to start a selenium PhantomJS session with a specific certificate?
Right now if I run it with PhantomJS I get `Missing certficate`. Adding `--ignore-ssl-errors` is not an option, this site needs the certificate.

I can use Chrome or Firefox and install the certificate first and then call `webdriver.Chrome()` and it will work, but is it possible to do this with PhantomJS?

Comment: @ArtjomB, HTTPS/SSL trusted root certificates

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean the use of client certificates, not the specification of other trusted CAs for validation of the servers certificate. Client certificates are not implemented (see [what is the correct way to feed an ssl certificate into phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001374/what-is-the-correct-way-to-feed-an-ssl-certificate-into-phantomjs)) while different trusted CA can be specified with the `--ssl-certificates-path` option.