# How to install SSL certificate in Python phantomjs?

Tags: python, ssl, phantomjs

How do I install a SSL certificate in PhantomJS with python?

[what is the correct way to feed an ssl certificate into phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001374/what-is-the-correct-way-to-feed-an-ssl-certificate-into-phantomjs)

Says in the command line, to use `--ssl-certificates-path`.

Comment: Have you tried passing the cli commands you need as a `service_arg`?

Comment: The question linked in your question has two good answers (those that are newer). What's not working?

Comment: @Vaviloff If you look closer at the linked question, you'll see it's about phantomjs console and not a Python implementation. My question is about a Python implementation, as I mentioned twice and tagged appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling answers [«what is the correct way to feed an ssl certificate into phantomjs»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001374/what-is-the-correct-way-to-feed-an-ssl-certificate-into-phantomjs) and [«Is there a way to use PhantomJS in Python?»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16659485/2715393) and taking into consideration that you haven't mentioned Selenium, I suppose your python script would look similar to this:

```
command = "phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-client-certificate-file=C:\tmp\clientcert.cer --ssl-client-key-file=C:\tmp\clientcert.key --ssl-client-key-passphrase=1111 /path/to/phantomjs/script.js"

process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# make sure phantomjs has time to download/process the page
# but if we get nothing after 30 sec, just move on
try:
    output, errors = process.communicate(timeout=30)
except Exception as e:
    print("\t\tException: %s" % e)
    process.kill()

# output will be weird, decode to utf-8 to save heartache
phantom_output = ''
for out_line in output.splitlines():
    phantom_output += out_line.decode('utf-8')
```

Another way to use PhantomJS from Python is with the help of Selenium automation tool. This way you would have to also provide necessary certtificate files via CLI:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-client-certificate-file=C:\tmp\clientcert.cer', '--ssl-client-key-file=C:\tmp\clientcert.key', '--ssl-client-key-passphrase=1111'])
driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
driver.get('https://localhost/test/')
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
driver.quit()
```

Note that providing custom ssl keys works in PhantomJS from version 2.1.

Comment: Oh, so there's no pythonic way to actually do it, but rather just run the commands from Python.

Comment: Please, define `pythonic way` then. Any solution will "run commands from python" because PhantomJS is not a python package, but a separate binary executed file.

Comment: Added Selenium example.