# login on phantom with an certificate.pfx

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

I want to use phantomjs and nodejs to login in a site using an PFX certificate, is it possible?

- The problem is that the server ask the certificate.pfx before the site loads.

I was able to do it using these commands:

--ssl-client-certificate-file= **path to pem file**

--ssl-client-key-passphrase= **pem file password**

--cookies-file= **file to store cookies** (./cookies.js)

--proxy-type=https (or http)

--ssl-certificates-path= **folder to store the site's certificates**  (./cert)

I wasn't able to use the .pfx file so I generated an .pem file using openssl, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413646/converting-pfx-to-pem-using-openssl).

And remember to get the site's certificates and put it in the **ssl-certificates-path** folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try supplying `--ssl-client-certificate-file` option on command line, look http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html for more related options.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001374/what-is-the-correct-way-to-feed-an-ssl-certificate-into-phantomjs should be related